# How do I import a texture atlas in SketchUp?

Tags: ios, macos, opengl-es, sketchup

I am following up the book *Learning OpenGL for IOS: A Hands-on Guide to Modern 3D Graphics Programming*, by Erik M. Buck.

The book provides a useful free tool called `COLLADAViewer` for converting COLLADA documents (*.dae files) into plist files loadable by OS/X or IOS. One of the limitations of `COLLADAViewer` is, it only uses one texture at a time; therefore all textures used by your model should be combined into one large texture atlas shared by other models.

The code sample includes a "texture atlas" and a sketchup file (*.skp) using textures from that atlas.

My questions are:

1. How do I create a texture atlas loadable from SketchUp?
2. How do I import a texture atlas in SketchUp, select and apply different textures from it on to different surfaces on my model?

Answer (score 0):

After playing with SketchUp a little I figured out how this can be done:

- How do I create a texture atlas loadable from SketchUp?

A texture atlas is bunch of texture images stacked up one after another. There is no hard rules to stack many texture images into one image file. Use your favourite image editor to do so. The important point is each texture segment in this file should have sufficient area to cover/fit into a designated surface on your model.

- How do I import a texture atlas in SketchUp, select and apply different texture areas from it on to different surfaces on my model?

On SketchUp, from `File/Import` menu, under `Format` selection box, select `Use As Texture` and press `Import` to import your texture atlas.

You just need to position/drag the image so that guide points on left-bottom and right-top of the target surface snap. At this stage don't worry about selecting the right texture area from atlas.

There is plenty of material on the Internet to show how to import a texture from an image file and apply it to a surface. This is one of them: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScuPF_CvFAk

There is one last step which is to position the right (intended) texture from many provided in the texture atlas. To do so, select the surface on which you applied the atlas texture. `Right-click` then from the context menu select `Texture/Position` option. This will bring up a grid of texture atlas images. With the hand icon you may drag the texture to align intended image area with the target surface. Once aligned, `Right-click` and press the `Done` button.

Answer (score 0):

right click on texture area, create material and select the new texture